# moving a wordpress website to a different url

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a wordpress website for a minecraft server, the server name changed, so the website domain changed. I tried moving the forums to the other url, by coping and pasting all the files but using the same exact database. However, as you use website, it links you back to the original website a lot. If is the problem that the main domain name is inside the mysql database? If i change all domains inside the database, will this fully move the website? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your wp-config.php file, enter the line `define('RELOCATE',true);`

Access your login page from http://yoursiteurl.com/wp-login.php, go to settings and change the site url.

Remove `define('RELOCATE',true);` from wp-config.php

Answer (score 0):

Moving a WordPress web site is quite well documented here:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

If not, it really is just as simple as copying all the files and the database. To avoid FTP transmission errors and such, I have had more luck with compressing all the files into a single .tar.gz file then FTP'ing that to my computer and to the new web site, where I expand it.

Personally, I use cPanel (the most popular web hosting customer account/web site management tool). Their Backup and Restore for the database. And their File Manager's Compress and Expand to work with the .tar.gz

Changing domain names significantly complicates matters. I use the [Search and Replace](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-and-replace/) plug-in to handle hard-coded URLs. Or manually find and replace the URL in the database script.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress has a whole guide on moving wordpress sites: http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

but the basic step is as follows:

1. goto: Administration > Settings > General panel, and change the site URLs there to your new url. this should update all post links, etc. in the database.
2. move files to new host
3. move database to new host.

Comment: Sadly, this will not change any url's which are previously save in db. Like image & other media path.

Answer (score 0):

Run this SQL to change url's in db.

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = REPLACE(guid, 'old-url.com', 'new-url.com');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'old-url.com', 'new-url.com');
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = REPLACE(option_value, 'old-url.com', 'new-url.com');
```